# Use urlfetchapp with own redirection?

Tags: google-apps-script, urlfetch

I am trying to do an urlfetchapp on a website, the website contains HTML but thats good enough for me.
For example I want [this url](http://www.knzb.nl/verenigingen/wedstrijdsport/waterpolo/uitslagen_waterpolo/iframe/verenigingen/poule/1208/378/DHS289F/).

The problem of this method is it won't show me any data until I first went to [this url](http://www.knzb.nl/verenigingen/wedstrijdsport/waterpolo/uitslagen_waterpolo/iframe/verenigingen/KNZB-DISTRICT-OOST/).

I tried to do 2 urlfetchapp after each other. But this didn't work.
How can I solve this problem?

Below is my test code, if there is data then objTable should get data.

```
function loadXML()
{ 
  try
  {
    var URL = "http://www.knzb.nl/verenigingen/wedstrijdsport/waterpolo/uitslagen_waterpolo/iframe/verenigingen/KNZB-DISTRICT-OOST/";
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(URL);
    URL = "http://www.knzb.nl/verenigingen/wedstrijdsport/waterpolo/uitslagen_waterpolo/iframe/verenigingen/poule/1178/2074/DHS289F/";
    response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(URL).getContentText();
    Logger.log(response);
    var doc = Xml.parse(response, true);

    var objTable = doc.html.body.form.div[1].div.div.div.div.div.div;
  }
  catch(err)
  {
    var objTable = "Load failed";
    Logger.log("Loading data failed: " + err);
  }
  return objTable;
}
```

Comment: I tried this code, and both urlFetch statements retrieved data.  The second urlFetch will retrieve data with the first one commented out.  The `var doc = Xml.parse(response, true);` statement is returning **XmlDocument**.  The `var objTable = doc.html.body.form.div[1].div.div.div.div.div.div;` statement is producing an error.  The `catch(err)` is catching an error and returning:  **Loading data failed: TypeError: Cannot read property "div" from undefined.**  Is `doc` a global variable?  Where is `doc` defined?

Comment: It will run en get some data. But the second website which I'm fetching, doesn't show the data as it supposed to be. If I want the data to show up as it supposed to be I need first to open the first page and after that the second page. Then in the browser it shows the correct data. If I fetched the correct data, there shouldn't be any error.

Answer (score 1):

I already found the answer to my own question.
Needed to resend the cookie. The script below is working as it should be.

```
function loadXML()
{ 
  try
  {
    var URL = "http://www.knzb.nl/verenigingen/wedstrijdsport/waterpolo/uitslagen_waterpolo/iframe/verenigingen/KNZB-DISTRICT-OOST/";
    var response1 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(URL);
    Logger.log(response1);
    var cookieStr = response1.getHeaders()["Set-Cookie"];
    var params = {method: "POST", headers:{"Cookie": cookieStr}};
    URL = "http://www.knzb.nl/verenigingen/wedstrijdsport/waterpolo/uitslagen_waterpolo/iframe/verenigingen/poule/1178/2074/DHS289F/";
    response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(URL, params);
    Logger.log(response.getAllHeaders());
    response = response.getContentText();
    var doc = Xml.parse(response, true);

    var objTable = doc.html.body.form.div[1].div.div.div.div.div.div;
  }
  catch(err)
  {
    var objTable = "Load failed";
    Logger.log("Loading data failed: " + err);
  }
  return objTable;
}
```